# How to deal with SOCKET in select method?

Tags: winsock, winsock2

I saw this example in IBM [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=designs-example-nonblocking-io-select) on how to use `select` method for a server program, I would like to something similar to that on windows without using `vector`s and `unordered_map` but the problem I am facing is that windows uses `SOCKET` for socket descriptors and linux uses `int` although I can cast the windows socket into an integer it is not recommended and the socket value is bigger than `FD_SETSIZE`, that being said the for loop ends before reaching the server socket descriptor and the function ends up being kind of useless

```cpp
int Server::handler()
{
    int iResult;
    timeval timeout;
    fd_set activeFdSet;
    fd_set readFdSet;
    FD_ZERO(&activeFdSet);
    FD_SET(serv_sock, &activeFdSet);
    printf("FD_SETSIZE=%d\n", FD_SETSIZE);
    // listen for incoming connections
    iResult = listen(serv_sock, SOMAXCONN);
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec= 0;

    while (1)
    {
        readFdSet = activeFdSet;
        printf("\tCopied activefdset to readfdset\n");
        int res = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readFdSet, NULL,NULL,&timeout);

        for (int i=0;i<FD_SETSIZE; i++)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(i , &readFdSet)) // check socket descriptor 
            {
                if (i == (int)serv_sock)
                {
                    // accept connections to the server 
                }
                else // client socket 
                {
                    // receive from client 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what is the best way to deal with the server socket in a for loop without using `vector`s or any other similar concepts

Comment: The FD_SET in Winsock is *designed* for `SOCKET`, of course. Get rid of all the `(int)` casts, and make `i` a `SOCKET` variable. You need to have a look at the MSDN Winsock documentation and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On non-Windows platforms, sockets are represented with file descriptors, which are basically indexes into a files table. That is why you can use `int` sockets as loop counters.

However, that is not the case with Windows sockets. A `SOCKET` is an opaque handle to an actual kernel object, so you can't use `SOCKET`s as loop counters, like you are trying to do. And do not cast them to `int`.

You really have no choice but to store the accepted sockets in an array or other container and then iterate through that instead, especially if you want the code to be portable across platforms, and particularly if you want to handle more than `FD_SETSIZE` number of clients (in which case, you should be using `(e)poll()` or other asynchronous socket I/O mechanism instead of `select()`), eg:

```
int Server::handler()
{
    int iResult;
    timeval timeout;
    fd_set readFdSet;
    int maxFd;

    // listen for incoming connections
    iResult = listen(serv_sock, SOMAXCONN);
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec= 0;

    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readFdSet);
        FD_SET(serv_sock, &readFdSet);

        #ifdef WIN32
        maxFd = -1; // not used on Windows
        #else
        maxFd = serv_sock;
        #endif

        for (each client_sock in list)
        {
            FD_SET(client_sock, &readFdSet);
            #ifndef WIN32
            if (client_sock > maxFd) maxFd = client_sock;
            #endif
        }
        #endif

        int res = select(maxFd+1, &readFdSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (res < 0) ... // error handling as needed...

        if (FD_ISSET(serv_sock, &readFdSet)) 
        {
            // accept connections to the server, add to clients list 
        }

        for (each client_sock in list)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(client_sock, &readFdSet)) // check socket descriptor 
            {
                // receive from client 
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, on Windows only, you can rely on Microsoft's documented implementation detail that `fd_set` has `fd_count` and `fd_array[]` members, so you can just iterate through the `fd_set`'s internal array directly, eg:

```
int Server::handler()
{
    int iResult;
    timeval timeout;
    fd_set readFdSet;
    int maxFd;

    // listen for incoming connections
    iResult = listen(serv_sock, SOMAXCONN);
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec= 0;

    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readFdSet);
        FD_SET(serv_sock, &readFdSet);

        #ifdef WIN32
        maxFd = -1; // not used on Windows
        #else
        maxFd = serv_sock;
        #endif

        for (each client_sock in list)
        {
            FD_SET(client_sock, &readFdSet);
            #ifndef WIN32
            if (client_sock > maxFd) maxFd = client_sock;
            #endif
        }
        #endif

        int res = select(maxFd+1, &readFdSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (res < 0) ... // error handling as needed...

        #ifdef WIN32
        for (int i = 0; i < readFdSet.fd_count; ++i)
        #else
        for (int client_sock = 0; client_sock <= maxFd; ++client_sock)
        #endif
        {
            #ifdef WIN32
            SOCKET client_sock = readFdSet.fd_array[i];
            #else
            if (!FD_ISSET(client_sock, &readFdSet)) // check socket descriptor
                continue;
            #endif
            if (client_sock == serv_sock)
            {
                // accept connections to the server, add to clients list 
            }
            else // client socket 
            {
                // receive from client 
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you prefer/recommend `poll` over `select`?

Comment: @loaded_dypper if you need to support more than `FD_SETSIZE` number of simultaneous clients, yes. This is even stated in the `select()` documentation on Posix systems, for instance https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html: "*WARNING: select() can monitor only file descriptors numbers that are less than FD_SETSIZE (1024)—an unreasonably low limit for many modern applications—and this limitation will not change. All modern applications should instead use poll(2) or epoll(7), which do not suffer this limitation.*"

Comment: @loaded_dypper however, on Windows, [`WSAPoll()` is broken](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/10/10/wsapoll-is-broken/), but there are other ways to handle large numbers of clients on Windows.